# What's the difference between ndarray.item(arg) and ndarry[arg]?

Tags: python, numpy

I read the [Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html), but still not quite understand the difference and the use case for `item`.

But recently I found where only `item` works:

```
a = np.array(100) # a has shape ()!
a.item() # or a.item(0)
```

This is the only way to get the value out of `a`, `a[0]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

`ndarray.item` allows you to interpret the array with a flat index, as opposed to using `[]` notation. This allows you to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))

print(a)
#[[ 0  1  2  3]
# [ 4  5  6  7]
# [ 8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15]]

print(a[2,2]) # "Normal" indexing, taking the 3rd element from the 3rd row
# 10

print(a.item(12)) # Take the 12th element from the array, equal to [3,0]
# 12
```

It also allows you to pass a tuple of indices easily, as below:

```
print(a.item((1,1))) # Equivalent to a[1,1]
# 5
```

Finally, as you mentioned in your question, it's a way to get the element of an array with `size = 1` as a Python scalar. Note that this is different to a `numpy` scalar, such that if `a = np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float32)` then `type(a[0]) !=  type(a.item(0))`.

```
b = np.array(3.14159)

print(b, type(b))
# 3.14159 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(b.item(), type(b.item()))
# 3.14159 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Another important distinction: the `item` method returns the value converted to a *Python* scalar (not a numpy scalar).   Let `a = np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float32)`, and compare `type(a[0])` and `type(a.item(0))`.

Comment: @Warren thanks for the distinction there, I've edited my answer to include it :)